# Why is .. (the parent directory) shown in my svn status -u output?

Tags: svn, directory, parent, output

I have checked out a Subversion repository on two different (Windows) machines.  On one, I run `svn status -u` and it correctly shows only the two files that I've modified on that machine.  On the other machine, one line of the output is:

```
?                    ..
```

presumably indicating that the parent directory isn't under version control.  Indeed, the parent directory isn't under version control, but it's not on the first machine either and that doesn't mention it!  I thought `svn status -u` only looks at directories and files at or beneath the current directory; is that not correct?!

EDIT: One difference between the two machines is that, although I'm using the `svn` command via Cygwin on both, one has v1.7.10 and the other (which shows the `..` line) has v1.8.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple answer to my question: it's not!

I've just discovered a directory called `..^M` (where `^M` is the newline character).  I've no idea where this came from, but that was what was being shown in the output; it's just that the `svn` command doesn't escape or encode non-printable characters in its output.